# how to refresh google access token with refresh token without SSL?

Tags: authentication, access-token, refresh-token

I have faced a problem to refresh google access token on server side.

```
        RestTemplate restTemplate = new RestTemplate();

        MultiValueMap<String, String> params = new LinkedMultiValueMap();

        params.add("client_id", clientSecrets.getDetails().getClientId());
        params.add("client_secret", clientSecrets.getDetails().getClientSecret());
        params.add("refresh_token", this.refreshToken);
        params.add("grant_type", "refresh_token");

        String result = restTemplate.postForObject(requestUrl, params, String.class);
```

Response I got from google authentication server is just 403 status code.
and message is like this

```
{"error":"internal_failure","error_description":"SSL is required to perform this operation."}
```

Is that compulsory to use SSL on my server just in order to refresh access token ?
It's been tested on my local server and does not attach any SSL to it.

References for this code is from below URL.
https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/OAuth2WebServer#offline

Comment: I solved this issue by adding 'https' protocol instead of 'http' protocol for google api

Answer (score 2):

I solved this issue by adding 'https' protocol instead of 'http' protocol for google api

I had called like

```
http://www.googleapis.com/oauth2/v4/token
```

but for SSL call

```
https://www.googleapis.com/oauth2/v4/token
```

is required to refresh access token

Comment: Thanks you saved my time.  i was calling wrong URL...